# Testing a java class

Tags: java, exception

What is the problem here? I am just simply trying to catch a custom exception depending on a if statement in my constructor, the entire code

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package question3_test;

/**
 *
 * @author jackandjill
 */
public class Triangle2 
{
    private int side1, side2, side3;
    private  double area;
    private  String message;    

    public  int getSide1()
    {
        return side1;
    }

    public void setSide1(int s1)
    {
        side1 = s1;
    }

    public  int getSide2()
    {
        return side2;
    }

    public void setSide2(int s2)
    {
        side2 = s2;
    }

    public  int getSide3()
    {
        return side3;
    }

    public void setSide3(int s3)
    {
        side3 = s3;
    }

   public Triangle2(int a,int b,int c) throws InvalidValueException
   {
    setSide1(a);
    setSide2(b);
    setSide3(c);

    try
    {
         if (!(side1 + side2 > side3) && (side2 + side3 > side1)&& (side1 + side3 > side2))

                 throw new InvalidValueException("Invalid Value");
    }
    catch (InvalidValueException excep)
    {
        message = excep.getMessage();
        //throw new InvalidValueException(message);
    }

    public double findArea(int side_1, int side_2, int side_3)
    {
        int s, a, b,c;
        a = side_1;
        b = side_2;
        c = side_3;
        s = ((a + b + c)/2);
        area = Math.sqrt(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c));
        //area =
        return area;
    }
   }
}
```

The problem  is at my catch statement, it is underlined in red and says never thrown in the corresponding try statement

Comment: What problem are you getting?

Comment: The problem is in the logic. Why would you throw and exception and immediately then catch it?

Comment: you catch the exception you throw inside your class. but method has throws ?!!

Comment: As a side comment, you should reuse standard exceptions when possible. In this case you could throw the built-in IllegalArgumentException for example.

Comment: @assylias yes but this is a requirement and hence I am forced to use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't throw an Exception class like in the below code: -

```
throw InvalidValueException;
```

You have to **make a new instance** of your exception, and then throw it: -

```
throw new InvalidValueException();
```

But, still there is some logic problem in your code. You have declared your `Exception` to be throws, but at the same time, you are handling it in the `catch` block itself. Why would you do that?

**UPDATE**: -

As per your modified post: -

```
try
{
   if (!(side1 + side2 > side3) && (side2 + side3 > side1) && 
        (side1 + side3 > side2))

       message = "Invalid Triangle";

} catch (InvalidValueException e) {
    message = "Invalid Traingle";
}
```

Since you are no-where throwing any Exception in your `try block`, the `catch block` will complain about that..

If you want to `throw` an exception and `catch` it in place, use it like this: -

```
public Triangle2(int a,int b,int c) throws InvalidValueException

      if (!(side1 + side2 > side3) && (side2 + side3 > side1) && 
            (side1 + side3 > side2))

           throw new InvalidValueException("Invalid Value")
}
```

And suppose you are using it from your `main` method, you should have a `try-catch` block there, to handle the declared exception in constructor.: -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Triangle triangle = null;
    try {
         triangle = new Triangle(2, 3, 4);
    } catch (InvalidValueException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If you handle the exception in your method only, you should not declare it in your method declaration.. But if you are not handling it, then you must declare that exception to be thrown.

**An exception should be either handled, or declared to be thrown** (*In which case, you should actually throw that exception*), **but never both**

See This tutorial for more about Exception: - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html

Comment: @noobprogrammer. What error message are you getting? You have modified your code..

Comment: illegal start of expression at my message = "Invalid Triangle";

Comment: I have editied my code again with your suggestion still the same

Comment: @noobprogrammer. Where are you catching your exception?

Comment: @noobprogrammer. And catch it at the place you are using it.. If you are creating your object  in your main method, enclose the code creating object within try-catch block to catch the exception.. See my last two codes. It will be clear for you.

Comment: Your   throw new InvalidValueException("Invalid Value"); is saying no arguments are accepted!

Comment: @noobprogrammer Then you can remove the argument.. just `throw new InvalidValueException()`.

Comment: @noobprogrammer. Have you given 1-arg constructor to your Exception class??

Comment: I dont understand your last comment but I am just using this line  if (!(side1 + side2 > side3) && (side2 + side3 > side1)&& (side1 + side3 > side2))
             throw new InvalidValueException(); but how to show the message that this is a invlaid triangle?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18001/discussion-between-rohit-jain-and-noobprogrammer)

Answer (score 2):

There is some confusion in your code in the way you use exceptions.

1. Inside the `try` block you never throw your exception, but try to catch it below.
2. You declare that your method throws the exception, but the method's body never throws it.

---

```
public Triangle2(int a,int b,int c) 
throws InvalidValueException // declared, but never thrown!
{
  try
  {
    if (!(side1 + side2 > side3) && (side2 + side3 > side1)&& (side1 + side3 > side2))
      message = "Invalid Triangle";
  }
  catch (InvalidValueException excep)  // caaught, but never thrown in try body!
  {
    message = "Invalid Triangle";
  }
}
```

This is the way you should write it, much simpler in fact:

```
public Triangle2(int a,int b,int c) throws InvalidValueException
{
  setSide1(a);
  setSide2(b);
  setSide3(c);
  if (!(side1 + side2 > side3) && (side2 + side3 > side1)&& (side1 + side3 > side2))
    throw new InvalidValueException("Invalid Triangle");
}
```

You are not supposed to catch the exception in the same context where you threw it: the place where you **use the constructor**, `new Triangle2(a,b,c)`, is the (earliest sensible) place to catch.

Comment: I am in the assumption that try simply tries to see if the statement is valid or not then catch will catch various kinds of exceptions. Isn't that so?

Comment: No, not quite. You put `try` around a block of method invocations that may result in an exception being thrown. You put `catch` blocks below with code to execute in case any of the methods called in the `try` block threw an exception. So it (almost) never makes sense to both *throw* and *catch* within the same method. The whole exception mechanism is there to allow you to **concentrate** error handling for a mass of code into a single place in your code.

Comment: Got that, but your simpler way is indeed simple but the fact is I indeed have to apply try-catch statement as I will be checking various other exceptions as well

Comment: @noobprogrammer Whatever exceptions you check, there is no sense in doing it within the constructor. If you are trying to say that you will be **checking** various other **conditions**, and **throwing** various other **exceptions**, then just repeat the same idiom and throw more exceptions in more if-blocks.

Comment: @BheshGurung It *could* be a `RuntimeException`. I'd certainly make it that. Why do you say, though, that it should be one, from the perspective of OP's code?

Comment: I have modified my original posting please see that I am still getting an error

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Because if I were to invoke that constructor then I would first make sure the values are valid. Moreover, I would like to avoid having to surround that call with a try/catch. Only thing, it would have to be documented. :)

Comment: @noobprogrammer No, your new code doesn't produce the compiler error you mention. I've checked it on my side. The only problem with your code is a misplaced `}`.

Comment: @BheshGurung As I said, that's the way I'd do it, but it is quite unrelated to this question.

Answer (score 0):

You should re-throw your custom `exception` from catch block .

```
catch (InvalidValueException excep)
{
    message = "Invalid Triangle";
    throw new InvalidValueException(message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `InvalidValueException` is a checked exception (compiletime exception) and your code within the catch block doesn't throw that exception.

You can overcome that error message (in a meaningful way) by first checking the values in your method and immediately throwing the exception if any of them are not valid.

Or, if possible, you can also make it a `RuntimeException` instead.